# Creating an image(greyscale) histogram using for loops

Tags: python, numpy

```
img = cv.imread('test.jpg')

    # displays the image
    cv2_imshow(img) 

    # initialize the array to store histogram
    h = np.zeros(256, np.int32)
    print(h)
    # get the row and column of the image
    row, col = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]

    # creates the histogram of the image
    for i in range(0, row):
      for j in range(0, col):
        h[img[i, j]] += 1
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(h)
    plt.show()
```

[image: this is the plot I get. it not correct]
[image: this is how it suppose to look like]

The first image is the histogram I got using my for loop, and the second one I got by using numpy histogram function which is what am supposed to get.
My question is, what am doing wrong with the code. Any tips on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's `img`'s *dtype*, are you the code you provided works? Also can you show the call you made to get the second graph (w/ `np.histogram`)?

Comment: After correcting some (syntax) errors in the given code, `h` and `np.histogram(img.flatten(), 256)[0]` are the same for some grayscale image. So, can't reproduce - especially without a proper [mre].